# OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use how to solve in python flask

Tags: flask

- Serving Flask app "ter" (lazy loading)
- Environment: production
  WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
  Use a production WSGI server instead.
- Debug mode: off
  i am running flask second time then this type of msg i am getting instead of first time why.

Comment: yes,now what to do in second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it happens in the second time because the first instance of your app listening to the port you have selected.